# Multi-Property lookup with Backbone and Underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a method on my collection called `activeCall` that takes an id as a parameter. This method does a `_find` with underscore and returns the first match. What I want to do is pass multiple parameters to the method, then have the `.get()` function use those params.

Here's what I currently have:

```
var Activities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Activity,
    url: "/activity",
    activeCall: function (Activity_id) {
        return _.find(this.models, function (item) {
            return item.get("Activity_id") === Activity_id;
        });
    }
});
```

Here is what I'd like to do:

```
var Activities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Activity,
    url: "/activity",
    activeCall: function (Activity_id, CallType_id) {
        return _.find(this.models, function (item) {
            //How do I use both Activity_id & CallType_id with the call to item.get()?
            return item.get("Activity_id") === Activity_id && item.get("CallType_id") === CallType_id;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, turns out `return item.get("Activity_id") === Activity_id && item.get("CallType_id") === CallType_id;` actually works. I tried it just for kicks earlier and it did not work. I must have been doing something wrong because it's working now.